# PyBossa does not seem to be loading tasks properly

Tags: pybossa

I am very new to PyBossa. I am testing it on my machine with the Vagrant/Virtuabox testing environment. I ran the server on the localhost and followed the directions for the Flickr Tutorial [here](http://docs.pybossa.com/en/latest/user/tutorial.html), but when I test the app, I get this frozen screen where the tasks are not counted and the image is stuck in "Loading" (I did populate and add tasks). This issue seems to occur when I test different apps that I have developed myself as well. Any suggestion for how to solve this would be awesome!

[image: The issue that I am encountering:]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you changed the name of the project, so the template from FlickrApp does not find the project name, and therefore it does not load any picture :-)

Can you open the template.html and update it to match your project shortname: flickerexampleamplexample

All the best,

Daniel

Comment: Thanks for the response Daniel! I've renamed all instances of the shortnames for the projects and this seems to work for FlickrApp but not for another plugin tutorial (EpiCollect --- https://github.com/Scifabric/app-epicollect).

Comment: You have to always use the the short_name of your project in your template, otherwise it will fail. Be sure to double check that always.